# ERROR running force:package:version:create: The package root directory is empty

Tags: salesforcedx

When I run command:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create --package ...
```

I get this error:

> ERROR running force:package:version:create:  The package root directory is empty.

All the code is in the project? why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I had ignored the directory in `.forceignore` file.

Removing the entry fixed it.